# Full-text search in date field with Elasticsearch

Tags: date, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I have `expiration_date` date field in my Elasticsearch and request from user to be able to "full-text" search in this field and I have only one input for this.

So my initial mapping is:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "expiration_date": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and as a value I have for example: `2021-08-27T10:48:00.293Z`.

User would like be able to search this by `2021`, `2021-08`, `2021-08-27`, `27-08-2021` and `08-2021`. For all this search terms I have only one input field which is   used to search in other fields as well (fields like `title`, `description` etc.).

My idea to achieve this was to introduce some [`multi-fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) to the base field. So something like:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "expiration_date": {
          "type": "date",
          "fields": {
            "yyyy-mm-dd" : {
              //what to do here?
            },
            "yyyy-mm" : {
              //what to do here?
            },
            "yyyy" : {
              //what to do here?
            },
            "mm-yyyy" : {
              //what to do here?
            },
            "dd-mm-yyyy" : {
              //what to do here?
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm wondering if this is doable this way? Is something similar doable in any way only at the Elasticsearch side? Or I should rather prepare something similar on my application side, send it to ES and just use it there?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the best solution would be to use the custom formats for `date` field in Elasticsearch:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "expiration_date": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "year||year_month||year_month_day||dd-MM-yyyy||MM-yyyy||strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can range query the field:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "range": {
          "expiration_date": {
            "gte": "27-01-2001"
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Where you can use any format specified in mapping.

This solution would be the most scalable: you can just add more formats (available [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#strict-date-time) or you can construct one) and reindex the data to support any new formats.

Comment: Do not work in my case unfortunately. My input could be for example: `27-01-2001 + some term` so I will need to catch the date from input at the application side. I'm wondering if it is possible at ES side...

Comment: having the same issue here.. found something worth reading: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#ranges-on-dates you could extract the date parameter from your search string using regex or create your own search syntax and translate it to ES syntax before making the call.